# Why there is no any Sql Server in Add Connection list

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional (I installed all components). 
Here is what I'm trying to do. I create a new ASP.NET project. Then I open Server Explorer (View->Server Explorer), right click on Data Connections and choose Add Connection. Then I choose Microsoft SQL Server and press Continue, but the 'Server name' list is empty. 
I launch Sql Server Configuration Manager and it shows that SQL Server is in running state (Agent and Browser are stopped)
Why there is no any Sql Server in Add Connection list? 
--------------------------------------------------------------
I allow remote filestream for SQl Server, so no I can choose server in the list, but when I enter new database name and click Ok I get a error "sql server was not found or was not accessible"
[image]

--------------------------------------------------------------
Here is a list of installed programs with 'SQL' filter
[image]

Comment: This needs better tags.  It's not about sql, per se. I would use sql-server, visual-studio and maybe asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured SQL Server to allow remote connections? By default, SQL Server Express Edition and SQL Server Developer Edition do not allow remote connections.

**For SQL Server 2005**:

[How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

**For SQL Server 2008**:

1. From start menu of SQL Server 2008, run SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. From left side view of SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration.
3. In the right view, you will see the list of SQL Server protocols. By default only Shared Memory is enabled. Enable the other protocols to get your SQL server to accept connections over the network.

Your problem appears to be that you have more than one SQL Server instance installed locally. You will need to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: I trying to use SQL Server on the same machine with Visual Studio, so I think it is not necessary to allow remote connections. In any case I have not  "SQL Server Surface Area Configuration" in Start->Programs->Microsoft SQL Server 2005->Configuration Tools menu

Comment: I allow remote client to have streaming access to FILESTREAM data (in SQL Server properties), so now I can choose a SQL Server in Add Connection list, but when I enter DataBase name (the list is empty and I type a new one) I get a error "the server was not found or accessible"

Comment: @Nike I believe that wouldn't allow a connection using TCP/IP.

Comment: I enable all protocols, but there is no effect. I attach a list of programs with 'SQL' filters to main post.